# Mvc access controller antiforgerytoken options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC and have a page like contact us. This page has a view and a controller with a action method create. That action method takes in a model and with that model it will add to a database and email users. Is there a way to lock down access to the controller meaning they need to use the view to get access to the controller action method create. I think people can find the model format and just keep hitting the controller. Something like antiforgerytoken but it’s not working in my application because of the classic mode. I get the message This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

Comment: what do you mean by "lock down"? The Antiforgery token is only there to prevent CSRF attacks. You can add a `verb` on the controller endpoint like `[HttpPost]` or `[HttpGet]` to restrict access.

Comment: Add the verb like ‘httpPost’ anyone can post to that controller they don’t have to use the view

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "not working in my application because of the classic mode."? 
Also, Are you also Validating the Antiforgery Token in the controller with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`?

Comment: ValidateAntiForgeryToken operation requires IIS to be in integrated pipeline mode. I can’t change this mode because of some old applications within this structure.